# How can I have the ViewController event handler have the `this` set to the view in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, viewcontroller

In ExtJS by default, when one creates a view and an associated controller and then define an event like this `myevent: 'onEvent'` the `onEvent` in the controller is executed with the `this` being the viewController.

Is it possible to have the `this` be the view?

Comment: I don't think this is possible (unless you do some custom listener defined in the controller)... this is usually why the first param of framework events is the class instance... e.g. something like [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3dk4)

Comment: Hmmm, this makes sense. Thank you @incutonez !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're wanting it is not possible out of the box.  However, you can set the listener's scope after your view is rendered.  [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3dk4) for reference.

```
Ext.define('MyViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.myView',

    onAfterRenderView: function(view) {
        view.on({
            customEvent: this.onCustomEventView,
            // Notice what we're using as the scope here
            scope: view
        });
    },

    onClickCustomEventBtn: function() {
        this.getView().fireEvent('customEvent');
    },

    onCustomEventView: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
});
```

To add a little more color, there is the idea of [defaultListenerScope](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-defaultListenerScope) on components, which allows you to create inline handlers on your view definition, instead of having to create a ViewController.  In this scenario, if you're using this class in a class that has a ViewController, you have the ability to control the `scope` property in the `listeners` block.  I can't find where this property is defined in the API docs, but the [View Controllers Guide](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/guides/application_architecture/view_controllers.html#application_architecture-_-view_controllers_-_listeners) explains it.

If our button class looked like this:

```
Ext.define('ChildButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
    alias: 'widget.myButton',

    // If we want class's to have handlers resolve to itself, this must be set
    defaultListenerScope: true,
    text: 'Fire Custom Event',

    onClickCustomEventBtn: function() {
        console.log('Firing from button class');
        this.ownerCt.ownerCt.fireEvent('customEvent');
    }
});
```

And we instantiated it like this:

```
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'myButton',
        listeners: {
            // If set to this, it'll use the class's handler def
            // If set to controller, it'll resolve to using the VC's def
            scope: 'this',
            click: 'onClickCustomEventBtn'
        }
    }]
}]
```

We'd expect the framework to look for `onClickCustomEventBtn` in the `ChildButton` class because we set `scope: 'this'`... if we simply removed `scope` or set it to `'controller'`, then it'd resolve to the handler in `MyViewController`.